# java.lang.noclassdeffounderror in same package?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

I've got a very simple android project -- two classes. Both in the same package, com.testPackage. When I have the two classes in two different files (classa.java and classb.java), and I invoke ClassB b = new ClassB() from ClassA, I get this error when running on my device;

```
java.lang.noclassdeffounderror
```

If I just drop the same class definition (minus the public specifier) into classa.java, everything works great. Is there something I need to do to have eclipse package this up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your file name is classa.java or ClassA.java ?

Comment: Does it make a difference? my class is ClassA, the file is classa -- good old windows helping me out with its case (in)sensitivity..